# Using Split View in Word 2007 with Print Layout

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

Is it possible to use the Split View with the Print Layout in Word 2007?  This was possible in Word 2003, but now it appears to only be possible in Draft Layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, go to the Draft Layout.  Then click on the View tab, and in the Window section click the Split button.  Select a split location.  Finally, click in each split and change its layout back to the Print Layout.

***ADDITIONAL INFORMATION***

Normally, the little splitter gripper can be found above the vertical scroll bar.  However, under certain circumstances, such as when the document map is visible, this gripper will disappear.  Splitting the view using the process described above causes the document map to close.